# Where does value pushed onto stack goes?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

I'm actually learning assembly and my actual problem is implementing a function in assembly with 7 arguments using c calling convention. The rule says that the first 6 arguments are passed to `rdi`, `rsi`, `rdx`, `rcx`, `r8` and `r9`. The rest arguments (right to left) are pushed onto the stack.

So, if I have a function like this:

```
extern void* asm_func(void *arg1, void *arg2, void *arg3, void *arg4,
                      void *arg5, void *arg6, void *arg7);
```

Then call it with this:

```
asm_func(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
```

If I guess correctly, the assembler will generate something like this:

```
mov    $1, %rdi
mov    $2, %rsi
mov    $3, %rdx
mov    $4, %rcx
mov    $5, %r8
mov    $6, %r9
push   $7
call   asm_func
```

Now, the 7th argument is pushed onto the stack. This is where I confused. Where does it goes?

My first guess was just to do `pop`. But, that just doesn't feels right to me. My second guess was to get the address of `rsp` subtracted by `0x10`. So, my implementation is like this:

```
asm_func:                          # asm_func as a linux system call interface
    mov         %rdi, %rax
    mov         %rsi, %rdi
    mov         %rdx, %rsi
    mov         %rcx, %rdx
    mov         %r8, %r10
    mov         %r9, %r8
    mov         -0x10(%rsp), %r9
    syscall
    ret
```

Is that a right implementation?

Those guesses are based on my understanding of how push and pop works. What I understand is whenever I push a value to the stack it means I put the value below (in offset) `rsp`. So, I suspect the value `push`ed onto the stack will go. Am I correct? Is the `push` instruction really put the value there?

Comment: Why `-0x10` though? It's `8(%rsp)` since `0(%rsp)` is the return address and the argument is right on top of that.

Comment: because the process of making a call pushes the return address (8 bytes) on the stack, right?

Comment: The manual for `push` explains exactly what it does: http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PUSH.html

Comment: Try that code in debugger, single stepping over `push $7` and `call asm_func` (use "step into") and watch how `rsp` does change, and memory area pointed at by `rsp` .. you will see how `push` does "add" 64 bit constant "7" ahead of old `rsp`, and then the `call` will "add" another 64b number of the return address (and `rsp` will be adjusted by -8 and -8 to point always at the "top" of the stack (last value pushed)). So then `+0(%rsp)` is return address and `+8(%rsp)` is your value "7". (otherwise "stack" is ordinary piece of memory, nothing special about it, implicit usage of `rsp` is special)

Comment: I assume this is for Linux. The Linux ABI seems to use these registers. Other ABIs, e.g. the Win64 ABI, do not. **For such questions, please always indicate the platform you are programming for**. Things are very different for different platforms. For istance, in Win64, syscall is not used at all. You rather link to named functions from the Windows API.

Comment: FWIW, 1, 2 etc. are not void pointers, so your asm_func() call should not work at all. You should be passing addresses. If you want this to work, change your declaration to `extern void asm_func(int arg1, int arg2,` etc...